# Device wont show up in Droid Explorer

Tags: droid-explorer

For some reason the Droid Explorer (and other apps) wont show my Samsung device at all.

The button "Restart ADB" works, but doesn't accomplish anything.

[image: The Select Device menu]

Using **adb** manually works perfectly and the device shows up too.

[image: adb devices -l]

[image: ADB version]

Comment: Hi, would you mind clicking on the [droid-explorer](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/droid-explorer) tag, maybe you can already find solution

Comment: Can you see it on the USB bus with the device manager?

Comment: Droid Explorer requires [TWRP](https://androidhost.ru/1O08) recovery